# can't assign value of type '()' to UIColor

Tags: swift

When i write following line of code, compiler shows error "can't assign value of type '()' to UIColor". Any explanation regarding this error ?

searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

Comment: This syntax working fine for me, gives no syntax error in swift 2.0

Comment: Try simply building the project. Sometimes Xcode parses for errors faster than you can type and you type valid code but it says there's an error. Happens to me every once in a while. Usually simply saving or building makes the error go away.

Comment: It was not working because broken sequence of code. I didn't notice. Thanks for checking it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in that syntax i tested on **Swift 2.0**

Try Cleaning you project and rebuilding

1. Go to **Product**
2. select **Clean**
3. Product>**Build**

And check it should work fine

sometimes **XCODE** parses for errors faster so it takes time to get away